# UITableView pull to refresh automatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I got a `UITableViewController` and the data of the list is get from the server.
Supporting scroll down to refresh data.

My question is when view did load. I don't want user use finger to pull it down get the data, but `UITableView` scroll down itself automatically and get data from server.

**Edit:**

Sorry, my question is there is a method named `pullDownToRefresh`, for example. If user use finger to pull down the `tableView`, the function is triggered. And now, I want to make `tableview` pull down by itself, and trigger the function automatically.

I also need to make `tableView` scrolls down. I tried `beginRefreshing`, but the `tableView` is not really scrolls down.

Comment: Don't understand your question.

Comment: Just invoke your method that fetches data from the server. There is no need to pull the table down

Comment: Please show some code to make others understand your problem

Comment: This happens to me to sometimes. Try setting the contentInset in your tableView

Comment: Sorry, my question is there is a methond named "pullDownToRefresh", for example. If user use finger to pull sown the tableview, the function is triggered. And now, I want to make tableview pull down by itself, and trigger the function automatically.

Comment: if you want this pull down to fresh called after some specific interval just disable the gesture in "pullDownToRefresh" method use nstimer in viewDidLoad() and call this new "pullDownToRefresh" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to programatically display the refresh control(without finger swipe) and reload your tableView.

UIRefreshControl's "**beginRefreshing**" method serves your purpose.

- Create a UIRefreshControl property in your UITableViewController
- Call beginRefreshing method on that property whenever needed
- call endRefereshing method when you have completed refreshing, reloading your tableView

More at this link :[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I also need to make tableview scrolldown. I tried "beginRefreshing", but the tableview is not really scrolldown.

Comment: beginRefreshing method just animates the spinner. To make it visible you might have to programatically set the contentOffset of the tableView.